# Optimalizing large amount of operations on Android

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on a particle system. It does a lot a LOT of calculations / calls on openGL Draw. So far I divided up the calculations so on every screen refresh it does a different part of the calculation it helps a lot but it is not enought.

I have 2 other ideas to improve the preformance:

1, Native code I know it should help but I have no idea how much and if it would worth the effort. Setting up and learning something new takes a lot of time.

2, Create threads to calculate different parts. Synchronizing could be a problem but at this point the only thing I care about is speed. The problem again I have no idea if it would help or not

My question is which method would be better or is there a better way that I didn't think about?

Comment: Do you need real-time rendering?

Comment: Native code won't help, I quote from Google: "Before downloading the NDK, you should understand that the NDK will not benefit most apps. As a developer, you need to balance its benefits against its drawbacks. Notably, using native code on Android generally **does not** result in a noticable performance improvement, but it always increases your app complexity. In general, you should only use the NDK if it is essential to your app—never because you simply prefer to program in C/C++.".

Comment: @XaverKapeller, do you have personal experience with that? Seems like this would benefit from NDK. The Google quote says "most" not all apps won't benefit.

Comment: You can also have a look at renderscript

Comment: @Athanor yes I want to interact with it that is why synchronizing would be a challange

Comment: Make fewer OpenGL calls, each one expensive either via JNI or crossing the over from CPU to GPU.

Comment: @XaverKapeller this is why I'm asking this question would it worth the effort? There is a lot of array reading/modifying ect, if NDK is not for this cases I don't know why would someone use it.

Comment: @MorrisonChang the problem is not with the openGL calls I use the bare minimum I use openGL to the display and I would use the NDK to calculate the things I want to display

Comment: @ZoltánNémeth Then you may be a candidate for Renderscript or NDK. Renderscript will give you easy/cheap parallelism. NDK will give you control/performance for a different price. As always profile your app and see what works.

Comment: I don't believe it will benefit your app. This warning from Google is pretty spot on, the NDK exists mostly just to make the porting of existing codebases easy.

Comment: renderscript seems promising I'll try that out

Comment: JVM is highly optimized, it can be as fast as native code.

Comment: RenderScript defenetly did the job, realy great tool